# ASP.NET Mail new line

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a variable that I am trying to use as my message for an email. The variable looks like this:

```
 var email = "aaa\n\n\n\nbbb";
```

What I am trying to do is a create a new line between aaa and bbb right now in my email the text looks like this:

```
aaabbb
```

and not:

```
aaa

bbb
```

I have also tried:

```
var email = "aaa<br /><br />bbb";
```

but in my message it looks like so:

```
aaa<br /><br />bbb
```

What am I doing wrong and how do I create a new line break.

Comment: Please show us how do you send an e-mail?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`\n` is for unix platform and `\r\n` for windows

Instead use `Environment.NewLine`. Does not look short and elegant, but is safe

```
var email = "aaa" + Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine + "bbb";
```

Answer (score 3):

In my ASP.NET app I used the following:

```
MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
mail.IsBodyHtml = true;
```

You can then use HTML markup in your message.  You could also use a Stringbuilder to insert your var and others into the email:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.AppendLine(var);
mail.Body = sb.ToString();
```

Comment: This is a good point, depending on the complexity of your mail and how many things you'll be appending to it ,a StringBuilder might be a good optimization to make.